# Problem with Newton's method for a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfawO.png)There are some exceptions when I try to find roots of nonlinear equations
I think that problem with def f(x):. Thank you in advance.
a = 3

```
def jacobian(f, x):
     h = 1.0e-4
     n = len(x)
     Jac = zeros([n,n])
     f0 = f(x)
     for i in arange(0, n, 1):
              tt = x[i]
              x[i] = tt + h
              f1= f(x)
              x[i] = tt
              Jac [:, i] = (f1 - f0)/h
     return Jac, f0


def newton(f, x, tol=1.0e-9):
     iterMax = 50
     for i in range(iterMax):
              Jac, fO = jacobian(f, x)
              if sqrt(dot(fO, fO) / len(x)) < tol:
                       return x, i
              dx = linalg.solve(Jac, fO)
              x = x - dx
     print ("Too many iterations for the Newton method")
n = 2


def f(x):
     f = zeros([n])
     for i in arange(0,n):
        f [1] = 3*x[n-1]^2 - x*[n-1] + x[n]*2 - 1  # my two equations
        f[n-1] = x[n] - math.tan(x[n-1])
     return f
x0 = zeros([n])
x, iter = newton(f, x0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the exact error messages you're getting so that the community understands the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of bounds according to the image. I think your problem comes in the two lines near the comment `#my two equations`. when you do `x[n]`, the array is out of bounds and i'm assuming that your array is size two. not forgetting that array sizes begin from 0 so you're accessing out of bounds array.

```
def f(x):
     f = zeros([n])
     for i in arange(0,n):
        f [1] = 3*x[n-1]^2 - x*[n-1] + x[n]*2 - 1  # my two equations - error is here when accessing x[n]
        f[n-1] = x[n] - math.tan(x[n-1]) # also here, accessing x[n] again
     return f
```